# C++ получение целой части от выражения с exp ( экспонентой )

Tags: c++

**Приветствую, форумчане.** 
Столкнулся с проблемой того, что у меня в ходе работы программы получается число с экспонентой, а по заданию мне так же требуется, цитирую "Найти сумму вычисленных значений функции f(x) целая часть которых кратна 2". Сама f выглядит вот так: 
[image: Функция задачи.]
.Я пробовал многое, пытался приравнять к переменной в которой хранится результат выражения, переменную с типом int, но в этой ситуации получается ноль. Пытался найти доп. материал в интернете, но т.к. **я только начинаю знакомство с C++** ( я студент первого курса ), то не особо принесли успех попытки что-либо найти. Так же, т.к. я только первокурсник, буду очень рад, если расскажете всё подробно и доходчиво для моего уровня знаний. **Так же поясню остальной код, там рассчитывается значений функций на интервале a<=x<=b; N - это количество результатов f в интервале.**
Вот мой **код** для наглядности:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a, b, x, n; // Условие.

    cout << "Insert a,b,n: "; 
    cin >> a >> b >> n; // получение данных условия.

    x = a;
    float f, dx = (b - a) / (n - 1);// формула шага.
    while (a <= x && x <= b)
    {
        f = (1 - exp(-x)) * sin(4 * M_PI * x);
        cout << "F = " << f << endl;
        x += dx;
    }

    getch();
}
```

**Вот само задание в полном объеме:** 
[image: Полное задание]

Спасибо за внимание, удачного времяпровождения, **форумчане**.

Comment: Какая степень у вас? Какое число после E?

Comment: Степень если честно не знаю. Т.к. интервал неограничен по условию и вводиться пользователем, то наверное определить заранее это невозможно. ( Чисто мои мысли. ) . Ну а вообще, если ввести a = 1; b = 6; n = 3; То число после e будет от -015 до -016

Comment: Читайте экспоненциальная форма числа. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C  Если у вас после E - отрицательное число - то это означает что ваш результат по модулю не превышает 1. Есть методы вывести число в "нормальном" виде, для с++ быстро не впспомню.

Comment: Как минимум при x>=0 f(x) всегда меньше 1, так что целая ее часть всегда 0.

Comment: Примерно -5 степень, после 5 числа после единицы, появляется e. Пример: -2.43271e-015

Comment: Кажись вот http://server.179.ru/tasks/cpp/total/151.html

Comment: Мне нужно не просто вывести данную целую часть от выражения, но еще и прибавить в накопительную переменную. Цитирую "Найти сумму вычисленных значений функции f(x) целая часть которых кратна 2"

Comment: Задача поставлена некорректно. Совершенно некорректно. Или дайте **полное** и точное описание задания, или вы тут получите... :(

Comment: Сейчас добавлю в тред полное описание задания. Секундочку.

Comment: Всё, я обновил тред и добавил полное задание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас x целое, а шаг вещественный, поэтому получался бесконечный цикл.

Вот ваша исправленная программа. Чтобы взять целую часть от числа используйте явное преобразование типов (int)f.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a, b,  n; // Условие.

    cout << "Insert a,b,n: "; 
    cin >> a >> b >> n; // получение данных условия.


    float x, f, dx = (float)(b - a) / (n - 1);// формула шага.
    x = a;
    float summ=0;

    while (a <= x && x <= b)
    {
        f = (1 - exp(-x)) * sin(4 * M_PI * x);
        cout << "F = " << f << endl;
        if (((int)f%2)==0){
                    summ=summ+f;
                   }
        x += dx;
    }

    cout << "Summ = " << summ << endl;

    getch();
}
```